# How to pivot 1 column and 2 rows into 2 columns and 1 row in Db2 SQL

Tags: db2

How to achieve 1 column 2 rows to 2 columns 1 row on DB2 please?

eg :

```
select value from <tablename> WHERE name='VAR' ORDER BY effectivedate DESC FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

which gives

```
VAR
----
12
57
```

But I want to get

```
VAR1,VAR2
-----------
12  ,57
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you mean you want to transpose the data? I am assuming that the '12 57' should have a carriage return between the values; please edit the question to clarify. Also please remove the DB2 tag from the title (StackOverflow standard for titling). Anyway, https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/pivoting_tables56?lang=en looks as if it might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the best way to "pivot" rows to columns is to aggregate over `CASE` statements.

For example

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN value END) AS VAR1
,      MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN value END) AS VAR2
,      MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN value END) AS VAR3
,      MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN value END) AS VAR4
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY effectivedate DESC) AS RN
    FROM a_table T
    )
```

will return this

```
 VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4
 ---- ---- ---- ----
   12   57    1 NULL
```

using the table and data in my other answer
which would return

Answer (score 0):

Use substring and aliases

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTR(VAR, 1,LOCATE(' ',VAR)-1) as VAR1
  , SUBSTR(VAR, LOCATE(' ',VAR)+1)   as VAR2
FROM YOURTABLE;
```

Basically breaking on space, if you have fixed length you can use without locate.

Comment: Thanks buddy,i tried but i did not get the results i wanted:)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. If you are on Db2 LUW 11.1 or above, this will work

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(VALUES 
   ( ( select value from a_table WHERE name='VAR' ORDER BY effectivedate DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY)
   , ( select value from a_table WHERE name='VAR' ORDER BY effectivedate DESC OFFSET 1 ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY )
 )) AS t(VAR1, VAR2)
```

and with this table and data

```
create TABLE a_table( value int, name char(3), effectivedate date);
INSERT INTO a_table values (12,'VAR','2018-01-10'),(57,'VAR', '2018-01-09'),(1,'VAR','2018-01-08');
```

will return this result

```
VAR1 VAR2
---- ----
  12   57
```

Comment: If you need a more generic answer, please improve your question, if not please up-vote/mark as answered